# ng test generates "TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation" error, but ng build works

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, karma-runner

When I try to run unit tests with 'ng test libraryprojectname' I get the error below.  ng build works fine though.  The project in question is a workspace with an angular library.    Any pointers on what to look for?

```
TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
    at Function.getCompilationHooks (C:\dev\MDM\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\JavascriptModulesPlugin.js:141:10)
    at SourceMapDevToolModuleOptionsPlugin.apply (C:\dev\MDM\node_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolModuleOptionsPlugin.js:50:27)
    at C:\dev\MDM\node_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:163:53
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\dev\MDM\projects\libraryprojectname\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:108:1)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (C:\dev\MDM\projects\libraryprojectname\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:14:14)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (C:\dev\MDM\projects\libraryprojectname\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1122:26)
    at C:\dev\MDM\projects\libraryprojectname\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1166:29
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\dev\MDM\projects\libraryprojectname\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\dev\MDM\projects\libraryprojectname\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at Compiler.compile (C:\dev\MDM\projects\libraryprojectname\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1161:28)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read another post about the casing in the project path being the issue.  I changed C:\dev\MDM... to C:\dev\mdm... & the error went away.